# Run a fetch call onLoad - React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.

I am trying to run a fetch call to get some data when my react page loads. I am not sure I am calling the event correctly though.

Here is how I am calling it:

```
export default function GetRecipe(props) {
  let { name } = useParams()
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('')
  const [recipeName, setRecipeName] = useState('')
  const [methodStepsList, setMethodStepsList] = useState([])
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([])

  const retrieveRecipe = function (e) {
    console.log('getting recipe')
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(searchQuery.length)
    let queryString
    if (searchQuery.length) {
      queryString = `http://localhost:3001/getbasicrecipe/?name=${searchQuery}`
    } else {
      queryString = `http://localhost:3001/getbasicrecipe/?name=${name}`
    }
    fetch(queryString, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json)
        let result = json
        let recipeName = result[0].recipe_name
        let recipeMethod = result[0].recipe_method.split(/\r?\n/)
        console.log(recipeMethod)
        setRecipeName(recipeName)
        setMethodStepsList(recipeMethod)
        setIngredients(json)
      })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="recipe-form-container">
        <form className="recipe-form">
          [...]
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

I read about `componentDidMount()` but could not figure out how to include it in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the whole code so that we can place it for you

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans I did my best but had to add more text due to Stack Overflow's rules to add the entire code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a class component then, as you mentioned you can use the componentDidMount() lifecycle method like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Runs after the first render() lifecycle
    retrieveRecipe();
}
...
render(){
...
}
```

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class

However if you are using a function component you should use instead the useEffect hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   retrieveRecipe();
}, []); // by using an empty array as dependency this useEffect will act as the componentDidMount function
...
return (
...
)
```

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    import React, {  useEffect } from "react";
    
    function YourComponent() {
     
   
      useEffect(() => {
      retrieveRecipie(e).then((res)=>{
       console.log(res);
  }
)
      }, []);
    
      return (
       <div></div>
      );
    }
    
    export default YourComponent;
```

mak you retrieveRecipie function

```
const retrieveRecipie= (yourParams) => {
  return fetch(
    `URL from where you are fetching data`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
body: JSON.stringify(yourParams),
    }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Class based component

```
componentDidMount(){
 //Your code here
}
render(){
return ...
}
```

If using function component

```
useEffet(()=>{
   //your code here
}, [])
```

return (...)

Answer (score 0):

this is a classic case of using [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook -

as in before the return function use -
`useEffect(()=>{ retrieveRecipe(); },[]);`

it comes instead of `componentDidMount`

I recommend to play a bit with react.js tutorial to get the hang of it before creating your own projects.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **Functional Component** of React JS, you don't need to handle the component lifecycle method manually. For functional component, there is **[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)** hook which will handle the lifecycle of the component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function GetRecipe(props) {
    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveRecipe();
    },[]);

    return <></>;
}
```

The above code will call the retrieveRecipe function only once after rendering this component.